# How to Programmatically Change Font in TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, fonts, twebbrowser

We are building an email client using a web browser in design mode. Our clients have their own specific font that they want to use. So we would like the ability to set the web browser font using the font they give us. The font they give us is just a string eg "Arial"

How can we set the browser font?

We have tried the following:

```
HtmlPage.execCommand('FONTNAME', False, 'Arial');
```

However this only does it for the selection and as the web browser is empty to start with there is no selection. As soon as the user starts typing the font changes back to times new roman.

I have also tried

```
HtmlPage := ((Sender as TWebBrowser).Document  as IHTMLDocument2);
while (Sender as TWebBrowser).QueryStatusWB( OLECMDID_SELECTALL) <> OLECMDF_SUPPORTED + OLECMDF_ENABLED do
        Application.ProcessMessages;
(Sender as TWebBrowser).ExecWB(OLECMDID_SELECTALL,OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER,pvaIn,pvaOut);
HtmlPage.execCommand('FONTNAME', False, 'Arial');
```

However, this is an infinite loop.

Any Suggestions would be appreciated :)
Thanks.

Comment: Do it in the style sheet. Or just ignore the users. They'll carry on using your software no matter what the fonts are and you could spend the time doing something more valuable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
((Sender as TWebBrowser).Document as IHTMLDocument2).body.style.fontFamily:='Arial';
```

Comment: Thanks this works, Just a note l required brackets around Sender As TWebBrowser